# Java: Getting index of 2 highest values in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

The following code returns the same index for top 2 maximum values:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> S_List = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    S_List.put(3, 18);
    S_List.put(9, 20);
    S_List.put(11,20);
    S_List.put(13,20);
    S_List.put(15,20);
    S_List.put(17,20);
    S_List.put(19,20);

    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> maxEntry5 = null;
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> maxEntry6 = null;

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : S_List.entrySet())
    {
        if (maxEntry5 == null || entry.getValue() > maxEntry5.getValue())
        {
            maxEntry5 = entry;
        }
        if (maxEntry6 == null || entry.getValue() > maxEntry6.getValue()
                  && entry.getKey() != maxEntry5.getKey()) {
            maxEntry6 = entry;
        } 
    }
```

The output is 17=20 for both Entry5 and Entry6, whereas it should be different indexes.

Also as a side question, how can I get 2 random indexes for top 2 values when all values are 20.

Comment: Keep in mind, that && has precedence over ||, so entry.getValue() > maxEntry6.getValue()  && entry.getKey() != maxEntry5.getKey() will be evaluated together, and then the result will be ORed with maxEntry6 == null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects should be compared using equals.

```
 if (maxEntry6 == null || entry.getValue() > maxEntry6.getValue()
              && ! entry.getKey().equals( maxEntry5.getKey())) {
        maxEntry6 = entry;
 }
```

But the major problem is the logic:

```
if (maxEntry6 == null || 
       entry.getValue() >= maxEntry6.getValue()
    && ! entry.getKey().equals( maxEntry5.getKey())) {
        maxEntry6 = entry;
    }
```

Even if the values are equal, you want another key's value.

A simpler solution would be the single if:

```
   if (maxEntry5 == null ||
       entry.getValue() >= maxEntry5.getValue()) {
        maxEntry6 = maxEntry5;
        maxEntry5 = entry;
   }
```